# クラスのメンバ変数に親クラスを持ち、その変数にインスペクタ上で子クラスを設定できるようにしたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

以下のCharacterクラスで_base_parameterにChildParameterクラスを保持したいです。
その際、インスペクタからChildParameter1を保持するのか、ChildParameter2を保持するのかを設定できるようにし、それぞれのメンバ変数を設定できるようにしたいのですが、どのような手段がありますか

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] BaseParameter _base_parameter;
}
[System.Serializable] public class BaseParameter　{ }
[System.Serializable] public class ChildParameter1 : BaseParameter 
{ 
    [SerializeField] _child1_parameter;
}
[System.Serializable] public class ChildParameter2 : BaseParameter  
{
    [SerializeField] _child2_parameter; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CharacterにSerializableクラスをSerializeFieldまたはpublicフィールドとして配置してしまうと、
インスペクタ上ではアタッチされたCharacter上に編集可能項目が展開されてしまいます。
また継承関係は考慮できません（エディタ上の項目はメンバ変数の型で決まるため）

ChildParameter2をインスペクタ上でパラメータ調整できるようにしたければ、
Serializableクラスで用意するのではなく、ScriptableObject継承クラスを使用します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①　CharacterはSerializeFieldメンバとして以下のようにします。
また、Instantiate（クローン）しないとlogicインスタンスの参照を共有してしまうため、Instantiateします。
（Logicがパラメータを持たない純粋なロジックなら不要ですが、Hpなど個々のゲームオブジェクトの情報を持つならクローンが必須です）

```
[SerializeField]
Logic _logicPrototype;

Logic _logic;

…

void Start()
{
    this._logic = Instantiate(this._logicPrototype);
    this._logic.Foo(); // 大抵の場合、MonoBehaviourの情報を渡して適切に初期化する
}

void Update()
{
    this._logic.Bar(); // やりたいようにやる
}
```

②　次に、個々のLogicChara1等のクラスは、以下の属性を付与することで、エディタのAssetsの右クリックメニュー> Createで.assetファイルとして作成できるようにします。

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Foo/Bar/LogicChara1")]
public class LogicChara1 : Logic
```

③　ここまでで準備は整いました。CharacterのlogicPrototype項目には、logicを継承したクラスに対する.assetファイルがどれでもアタッチできるようになります。

ScriptableObjectの使い方はしっかり理解するまで難しいですが、適切に使うと非常に便利です。
時間をかけて仕様や使い方を覚える価値は十分にあると思うので、いろいろ調べてみてください。